# BindJSON does not return error when Input is wrong

Tags: go, go-gin

Following is what I am trying

```
func TestCreteJob(t *testing.T) {
    requestBody, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
        "username": "u1",
        "password": "p1",
    })
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Test Failed ")
    }

    res, err := http.Post("http://127.0.0.1:9090/job", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    greeting, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", greeting)
}
```

and My Handler is like below

```
func Handlers() *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.Default()

    // Sample API
    router.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    router.POST("/job", func(c *gin.Context) {
        if c.Request.Method == "POST" {
            var u User
            err := c.BindJSON(&u)
            if err != nil {
                c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
            }
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
                "user": u.Username,
                "pass": u.Password,
            })
        }
    })
    return router
}
```

I have defined object as

```
type User struct {
   Username string `json: abc`
   Password string `json: password`
}
```

This should fail since input does not have 'abc'
Am I doing something wrong here.

Comment: If you want it to fail you would first have to specify some "binding" validation rules for the fields. See https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation. For example `Username string \`json:"abc" binding:"requried"\``.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct tags are wrong for the json

```
type User struct {
   Username string `json:"abc"`
   Password string `json:"password"`
}
```

Take a look here 
https://play.golang.org/p/oj_PwLoX5qs

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    dataz := []byte(`{"abc": "sberry", "password": "hunter2"}`)

    var u User

    err := json.Unmarshal(dataz, &u)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", u)
}

type User struct {
    Username string `json:"abc"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What should happen when the json is like below `dataz := []byte(`{"abc11": "sberry", "password": "hunter2"}`)`

Comment: @Avinash the `password` will be unmarshaled but `abc11` will not since it does not match any tag in the target struct, and the struct's `Username` field, with tag `abc`, will stay untouched.